# How to enable users to search for products in any language in OpenCart 3.0.3.8.?

Tags: php, mysql, search, opencart, opencart-3

I have a multi-language (English, Russian, etc.) website based on OpenCart 3.0.3.8. and the Journal 3 theme.

Currently, when using the search bar to search for products, if the user does not input text in the currently active language (let's say English), but in stead, inputs text in any of the other avaiable languages (for example, Russian), then the search will result in nothing being found.

Despite the product that coresponds with the search query being in stock, avaiable and having description translated in multiple-languages, OpenCart only looks for text in the active language translation and only text that matches the search query.

Ideally, I would like to allow users to write their search query in any of the avaiable languages... no matter which one is the active one currenlty and be able to find products.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

I have looked into the OpenCart support forum and people recommended to modify the product.php (catalogue) file function that supposedly contains the sql queries for fetching products based on search bar input.

For example, inside the getProducts() function I changed the following code...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";
```

...to this...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id);
```

I have also removed the pd.language_id restriction in other code blocks, but no matter what changes I introduce inside this file, nothing changes.

It is possible that the Journal 3 theme has it's own files that modify the default search functionality. Yet, the Journal theme documentation states (might be wrong) that Journal 3 uses the default built-in search functionality of OpenCart 3. Thus, modifying the default code responsible for searching prodcuts, should do the trick.

Yet, nothing I have tried has enabled my site to allow multi-language product search.

**UPDATE 1**

I have realized that the code responsible for the searching function is in a completely different file because of Journal 3. The Journal 3 documentation, claims that it just uses the default OpenCart search functionality. To an extent... That is true. However!

The file, responsible for product searching, is found in "catalog\controller\product\search.php" which in turn has the class "ControllerProductSearch".

It is a pretty, relatively huge file... At least for a beginner like me...

```
<?php
class ControllerProductSearch extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('product/search');

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $search = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $search = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['tag'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $tag = $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $tag = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $description = $this->request->get['description'];
        } else {
            $description = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $category_id = $this->request->get['category_id'];
        } else {
            $category_id = 0;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $sub_category = $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        } else {
            $sub_category = '';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $order = 'ASC';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $page = (int)$this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $page = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = (int)$this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            $limit = $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->request->get['search']);
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->language->get('heading_tag') . $this->request->get['tag']);
        } else {
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', $url)
        );

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title') .  ' - ' . $this->request->get['search'];
        } else {
            $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        }

        $data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));

        $data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

        // 3 Level Category Search
        $data['categories'] = array();

        $categories_1 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories_1 as $category_1) {
            $level_2_data = array();

            $categories_2 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_1['category_id']);

            foreach ($categories_2 as $category_2) {
                $level_3_data = array();

                $categories_3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_2['category_id']);

                foreach ($categories_3 as $category_3) {
                    $level_3_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $category_3['category_id'],
                        'name'        => $category_3['name'],
                    );
                }

                $level_2_data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category_2['category_id'],
                    'name'        => $category_2['name'],
                    'children'    => $level_3_data
                );
            }

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $category_1['category_id'],
                'name'        => $category_1['name'],
                'children'    => $level_2_data
            );
        }

        $data['products'] = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_name'         => $search,
                'filter_tag'          => $tag,
                'filter_description'  => $description,
                'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
                'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
                'sort'                => $sort,
                'order'               => $order,
                'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
                'limit'               => $limit
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($result['image']) {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                } else {
                    $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
                }

                if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                if (!is_null($result['special']) && (float)$result['special'] >= 0) {
                    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                    $tax_price = (float)$result['special'];
                } else {
                    $special = false;
                    $tax_price = (float)$result['price'];
                }
    
                if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                    $tax = $this->currency->format($tax_price, $this->session->data['currency']);
                } else {
                    $tax = false;
                }

                if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,
                    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['sorts'] = array();

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
                'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
                'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-DESC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
                );

                $data['sorts'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
                    'value' => 'rating-ASC',
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
                );
            }

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
            );

            $data['sorts'][] = array(
                'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
                'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', 'sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
            );

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            $data['limits'] = array();

            $limits = array_unique(array($this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit'), 25, 50, 75, 100));

            sort($limits);

            foreach($limits as $value) {
                $data['limits'][] = array(
                    'text'  => $value,
                    'value' => $value,
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&limit=' . $value)
                );
            }

            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
                $url .= '&search=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
                $url .= '&tag=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['tag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
                $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
                $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
                $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $pagination = new Pagination();
            $pagination->total = $product_total;
            $pagination->page = $page;
            $pagination->limit = $limit;
            $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/search', $url . '&page={page}');

            $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

            $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? (($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $limit) > ($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : ((($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), $product_total, ceil($product_total / $limit));

            if (isset($this->request->get['search']) && $this->config->get('config_customer_search')) {
                $this->load->model('account/search');

                if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
                    $customer_id = $this->customer->getId();
                } else {
                    $customer_id = 0;
                }

                if (isset($this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
                    $ip = $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                } else {
                    $ip = '';
                }

                $search_data = array(
                    'keyword'       => $search,
                    'category_id'   => $category_id,
                    'sub_category'  => $sub_category,
                    'description'   => $description,
                    'products'      => $product_total,
                    'customer_id'   => $customer_id,
                    'ip'            => $ip
                );

                $this->model_account_search->addSearch($search_data);
            }
        }

        $data['search'] = $search;
        $data['description'] = $description;
        $data['category_id'] = $category_id;
        $data['sub_category'] = $sub_category;

        $data['sort'] = $sort;
        $data['order'] = $order;
        $data['limit'] = $limit;

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/search', $data));
    }
}
```

I am assuming that this is where I need to introduce the changes into the code. The good thing is that, changing the code in this file, does update the search resulrs, but I dunno what I need to change to enable multi-language search.

```
if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_name'         => $search,
                'filter_tag'          => $tag,
                'filter_description'  => $description,
                'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
                'filter_sub_category' => $sub_category,
                'sort'                => $sort,
                'order'               => $order,
                'start'               => ($page - 1) * $limit,
                'limit'               => $limit
            );

            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

Comment: Throw all the various language versions of the product name into a single FULLTEXT-indexed column.  Then a single MATCH will find it in any case.  (That's MySQL-speak; I don't speak OpenCart.)  Caveat: Chinese, which does not have "letters", does not work well with FT.

Comment: Keep in mind that editing the core files of OpenCart is not a good idea. Any further update of your application would overwrite these changes

Comment: I eventually transported all my changes into an OCMOD file and uploaded the file as a modification.

Answer (score 0):

if you changed the journal and cleared the cache and reloaded everything (journal, opencart) and still didn't get the expected result, then it would be worth seeing where the journal is attacking this, as in common practice it would just be to remove the clause language itself.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I was able to find the main function that Journal 3 uses for product searching. I added it inside OP under UPDATE 1. Changing the code in the mentioned file and code does change the search functionality. Yet, I do not know what I need to specifically change to enable multi-language search.